# Access assets files from another class

Tags: android

Sorry for my English. I have a class named Server and I need to read URL from a file in my applications assets but `AssetManager` android studio says it cannot be accessed from outside package and `getassets()` don't work neither. How can I access assets from not activity class?

Comment: Provide the URL when you construct your instance of `Server`, either via a constructor parameter or a setter method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access assets from not activity class

To access assets you need `Context`. So pass one to your class (via constructor or other way) or just pass your URL if that's all you need from your assets

Answer (score 0):

Non Activity Class

```
public CustomClass(Context myContext) {
AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
InputStream is = mngr.open("text.txt");   // get text file 
 try {
     InputStream bitmap = myContext.getAssets().open("imagename.png");// get iamge file 
     Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
     //imgview.setImageBitmap(bit);
     }
    catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Call the class like as

```
     CustomClass(getApplicationContext()) ;              //activity
     CustomClass(getActivity().getApplicationContext());  //fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

I think getAssets only works within Activity Class. One of the ways to apply it in ordinary class is by creating constructor with Context parameter the reference getAssets within the constructor.

```
public DataFile(Context DataContext){
        try {
            AssetManager am = DataContext.getAssets();// If this line gives you ERROR then try AssetManager am=getActivity().getAssets();
            InputStream mInpuStream = am.open("Question.xls");
            Workbook mWorkBook = jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(mInpuStream);
            Sheet mSheet = mWorkBook.getSheet(0);
            int mRow = mSheet.getRows();
            int mCol = mSheet.getColumns();
            String mContent = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < mRow; i++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < mCol; c++) {
                    Cell mCell = mSheet.getCell(c, i);
                    mContent = mContent + mCell.getContents();

                }
                mContent = mContent + "\n";
            }
            display(mContent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```